# How Detect second screen

Tags: c#, console-application

I m a C# developer.
I have two screen(monitor) and I use this line of code:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" , @"C:\advertise.mp4");
```

to start My Windows Media Player.My question is that how can chose my process to start on second screen(monitor)?

Comment: `Screen.AllScreens[1]`

Comment: Generally speaking, it helps to google your question first. Chances are, somebody did it before you.

Comment: Edited my answer with a link to how you can start a process on a different screen.

Answer (score 4):

As Banana mentioned in the comments, an easy and effective way to  detect a second screen would be to add a reference in your project to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and then utilize the static `AllScreens` property of the `Screen` class, which returns an array of `Screen` instances. The following is a code sample just getting the count, but you could also find out other information such as detecting which of them is currently considering the Primary monitor in the system.

`// using System.Windows.Forms
int screenCount = Screen.AllScreens.Length;`

Answer (score 0):

Like Banana commented: Using the [Screen class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx) you will be able to use it's `AllScreens` property.

From there you are able to take out the desired screen you wish to use by `index`:

```
var screens = Screen.AllScreens;
var screen = screens[1];
```

If you are using more than 2 screens using the `DeviceName` could be the way to go:

```
var screen = screens.Single(x => x.DeviceName == "name of the monitor");
```

As stated by Kyle Burns in his answer:

> you could also find out other information such as detecting which of them is currently considering the Primary monitor in the system

**Edit:**

[Here is a solution on how to start a process on a different screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034115/start-process-on-specific-screen)

Answer (score -1):

```
var screens = Screen.AllScreens; 

var count = screens.length;
```

You can also iterate trough the screens

```
screens.ForEach(screen => {
    //do something with screen object
});
```