# How to get window's position?

Tags: c#, process, window, position, intptr

I'd like to know the way of getting process'es window position. I've been looking for that on the internet but with no results. Thanks :)

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
Process lol = processes[0];

IntPtr p = lol.MainWindowHandle;
```

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364440/how-to-get-and-set-window-position-of-another-application-in-c-sharp

Comment: What you want to do with it? [ Exit from antivirus with his window :) ]

Comment: lol, is that the only use for getting window's position you can think of?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string strClassName, string strWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);

public struct Rect {
   public int Left { get; set; }
   public int Top { get; set; }
   public int Right { get; set; }
   public int Bottom { get; set; }
}

Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
Process lol = processes[0];
IntPtr ptr = lol.MainWindowHandle;
Rect NotepadRect = new Rect();
GetWindowRect(ptr, ref NotepadRect);
```

Comment: It will work. Ok. But this code will not work when notepad has been minized to taskbar. You should check that. ( Also, I suggest to use try-catch to avoid "notepad is NOT running" error )

Comment: the Rect member var has wrong order. It should be Left, Top, Right Bottom. Otherwise, you will get incorrect values.

Comment: 100% sure `lol` variable once stood for league of legends window :P

Comment: Why have you got the FindWindow function included?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it does not work for Microsoft Sticky Notes? I'm using Windows 10. On doing `GetWindowRect` for sticky notes, I am getting a rectangle with X=Y=0, and Width = Height = 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;


public class GetNotePadLocation
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string strClassName, string strWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);

    public struct Rect
    {
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Top { get; set; }
        public int Right { get; set; }
        public int Bottom { get; set; }
    }
    public static void NotePadLocation()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        Process lol = processes[0];
        IntPtr ptr = lol.MainWindowHandle;
        Rect NotepadRect = new Rect();
        GetWindowRect(ptr, ref NotepadRect);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have found the missing part and there where order error in the struct part; I have fix it...

but I actually don't know how to get these property for all the opened notepad windows and how to get the dimension of the active one

thanks for the help...

Comment: to find the active window, have you tried `[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();` and call the function by `IntPtr handle; handle = GetForegroundWindow();`? For the all opened windows, please try `handle = FindWindowA(null, null);`