# Get window position and size C#

Tags: c#, position

How can I get the size and the position of a Window in C#?
I read about the `GetWindowRect` function, but I do not understand how to use it.
Can anyone please give me a example on how to use it? (I'd like to get the position of notepad++)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9669149/2300466

Answer (score 0):

`Form.Location.X` and `Form.Location.Y` will give you the X and Y coordinates of the top left corner.

For your own Form application is the code this.

Answer (score 0):

for your own program,
you can use these options,
"Size",
"Location",
otherwise you need to use "Screen" to get monitor size and get other app window size you want