# Can you get the position of a window that is inside of another application

Tags: c#, window, window-position

So I found an example from [an answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364440/how-to-get-and-set-the-window-position-of-another-application-in-c-sharp)

There was an answer that gave this example of code to move the Notepad window to the top left corner of the screen.  I tried it and it worked fine.  I then tried it on a small project I am working on and I couldn't move it.

NOTE: I did change the "Notepad" to the name at the top of the window I wanted to move.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // For the P/Invoke signatures.

public static class PositionWindowDemo
{

// P/Invoke declarations.

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const uint SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;

public static void Main()
{
    // Find (the first-in-Z-order) Notepad window.
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("Notepad", null);

    // If found, position it.
    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // Move the window to (0,0) without changing its size or position
        // in the Z order.
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
}
```

}

I will give an example.  Consider Visual Studios and how it has the Solution Explorer Window or the Output window, and I can drag them with the mouse and move them or undock them.  Would there be a way to have an application that has windows inside of it similar to Visual Studios and get the position of them in a program?

I have seen many answers on here about moving a window or finding the active window etc.  However I am not sure if I will be able to access this subWindow that is inside of another application.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you should be able to, however getting the handle to your sub windows might be a little more tricky. have you tried enumerating all the windows of the application and see if its there

Comment: I just did. But I did not see anything about the extra windows.  I opened 3 sub Windows just to check

Comment: It turns out the windows are owner-drawn. I guess this means there is nothing I can do?

Comment: I was just about message on this, have you tried looking with spy++, to make sure they are truly just painted on and not part of a control ie no handle

Comment: Yes I just did it and it shows no handle or any information about the window